# Extjs - Datepicker, disabledCellCls style not getting applied

Tags: extjs, datepicker

while trying to change the background color of disabled dates to red, using [disabledCellCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-cfg-disabledCellCls) seems to have no effect on disabled dates. How to make this work..

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4io

Thanks

Comment: It's a bug. The date picker hard codes the value and they aren't configurable. I'll log a ticket.

Comment: thanks for the info, will look for workaround now..

Answer (score 0):

Since this a bug, one workaround is to use 'cls' config instead of 'disabledCellCls' and additional selectors in css `.x-datepicker-disabled a.x-datepicker-date`

Sample fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4ph